# SQL Query Ordering by 0

Tags: sql-server

I have the below query:

```
SELECT distinct sending_organisation AS [Supplier], t1.date, COUNT(Status) AS [Transactions],  Month(t1.Date) SO_Month, Year(t1.date) SO_Year
 FROM tx

   CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (CONCAT(left(DATENAME(mm, Date_Reported),3),' ',
                             DATENAME(yyyy, Date_Reported)),
                      DATEPART(mm, Date_Reported)
                     )
            ) t1 (Date, Morder)

where  Date >= DATEADD(MONTH, -13, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
GROUP BY t1.date, t1.Morder, sending_organisation
ORDER BY sending_organisation, date DESC;
```

The query gives me a list of suppliers and their transactions for the last year. What I want is a dynamic query to alter the above and allow me to only select the last year's data for suppliers who have '0' transaction value for the current month.

Any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't `HAVING COUNT(Status) = 0` at the end before the "order by" solves your problem?  You need to specify to us what is "transaction value", as you are listing only "transaction count", I'm not sure if those are the same thing to you.

Comment: I have defined the count(status) as my transactions. If I do the above it will give me nothing as there are no instances in my data where status = 0. I want 'transactions to be =0- does that make sense

Comment: "Transactions" is your alias for "COUNT(Status)". You said you want transactions to be 0, but also said that there are no COUNT(Status) 0. Is this column returning the correct values for you? I guess you meant to use `SUM(CASE WHEN Status IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)`

Comment: "Transactions" is your alias for "COUNT(Status)".- that is correct. Yeh I want my alias column transactions to return all values that are 0 for THE CURRENT MONTH, so the list of suppliers will only be those who have a '0' in their transactions for this month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Determine which suppliers don't have a transaction for current month with `NOT EXISTS`, then join against their previous data.

```
;WITH Data AS 
(
    -- This is your query without modifications
    SELECT distinct 
        sending_organisation AS [Supplier], 
        t1.date, 
        COUNT(Status) AS [Transactions],  
        Month(t1.Date) SO_Month, 
        Year(t1.date) SO_Year
    FROM 
        tx
        CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (CONCAT(left(DATENAME(mm, Date_Reported),3),' ',
                             DATENAME(yyyy, Date_Reported)),
                      DATEPART(mm, Date_Reported)
                     )
            ) t1 (Date, Morder)
    where  
        Date >= DATEADD(MONTH, -13, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
    GROUP BY 
        t1.date, 
        t1.Morder, 
        sending_organisation
),
AvailableSuppliers AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        Supplier = sending_organisation
    FROM
        tx AS D
),
CurrentMonthTransactionZero AS
(
    -- Determine which sending_organisation have no transactions on the current month
    SELECT
        A.Supplier
    FROM
        AvailableSuppliers AS A
    WHERE
        NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT
                'no transaction for current month'
            FROM
                tx AS T
            WHERE
                A.Supplier = T.sending_organisation AND
                Date_Reported >= DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -1)) AND -- First day of current month
                Date_Reported <  DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE())) -- First day of next month
            )
)
SELECT
    D.*
FROM
    CurrentMonthTransactionZero AS D
    INNER JOIN CurrentMonthTransactionZero AS C ON D.Supplier = C.Supplier
```

Comment: Thanks @Ezlo, however this gives me no rows?

Comment: @Taz Make sure that you have at least 1 organisation with current month's transactions count = 0, otherwise it won't give you any result.

Comment: I definitely do @Ezlo, but not sure why it doesn't give me any rows.

Comment: @Taz try querying for organisations with 0 transactions for current month with the query from the edition.

Comment: it comes with an error "Column 'tx.Sending_Organisation' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: @Taz There were errors with the Supplier alias, I've edited it.

Comment: okay this works and comes back with a list with one supplier called "TEST"- do you think that original query does not give those with 0 transactions a value and classes them as null when i want a value of 0 in there. If i run my original query i get a list of suppliers that only have transactions. So for supplier A it will show Mar 18 and Apr 18 figures as the rest of the year have transactions of 0 including this month but it does not show up as a row. Does this make sense?

Comment: @Taz yes, it's true. You won't be able to get a count transaction of 0 with your first query. You have 2 options I can think of, either use a calendar table to `LEFT JOIN` against transactions so you can display missing months, or do a `SELECT ... WHERE NOT EXISTS` of the current month.

Comment: I think your query works fine and i just need to amend my query. Can you help me with this please, i'm not sure what a calendar tables is sorry. Nevertheless i have marked your answer as the answer

Comment: @Taz I've edited the whole response, try the query now, it should give you what you need. I'm assuming that `Date_Reported` is a `DATE` or `DATETIME` (will need a tweak if it's a varchar).

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are after? So I have used dynamic SQL for this, any string in SQL server can be executed as a SQL command using [`EXECUTE/EXEC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). I added your exact query as a string with a place holder value to add the extra where clause in the `IF` block after. Here I have left space for you to add your condition in on whether or not you want to add that extra where clause to your statement, if not then the place holder is removed so the select query can still run.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)=
'SELECT DISTINCT sending_organisation AS [Supplier], 
                 t1.date, 
                 Count(status)  AS [Transactions], 
                 Month(t1.date) so_month, 
                 Year(t1.date)  so_year 
 FROM            tx 
 CROSS apply     ( VALUES 
                 ( 
                                                 Concat(LEFT(Datename(mm, date_reported),3),'' '', Datename(yyyy, date_reported)), 
                                 Datepart(mm, date_reported) 
                 ) 
                 ) t1 (date, morder) 
 WHERE           date >= Dateadd(month, -13, Cast(Getdate() AS DATE)) 
 placeHolder 
 GROUP BY        t1.date, 
                 t1.morder, 
                 sending_organisation 
 ORDER BY        sending_organisation, 
                 date DESC; ';
IF(condition)
BEGIN
    SET @sql = replace(@sql,'placeHolder','AND WHERE transactionValue = 0 ');
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
    SET @sql = replace(@sql,'placeHolder',' ');
END
EXEC(@sql);
```

Comment: Thank you for this, sorry there is a fair bit going on here and my sql is not the best. Can you explain?